# Bad start tag in img in head error

Tags: html, markup, html4, markup-extensions

I am trying to validate my markup,following is my html code.When i validate it,says the error

```
Error: Bad start tag in img in head.
```

These are  the tags where i use to get errors

```
<noscript>
  <img height="1" width="1" class="displaynone" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1007528252627508&ev=PageView&noscript=1">
</noscript>
```

I think the error is  tag should not contain any tag except  , , and  elements but i am not  sure can  anyone  find  what  the exact  issue?

Comment: Why is this tagged `html4` AND `html5`?! What do XAML Markup Extensions have to do with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<head>` element is a container for metadata and is placed between the `<html>` tag and the `<body>` tag like what style you will add to your html page what script will be running. You can't add `<img>` tag in head. Doesn't matter it is `<noscript>`.
Remove your `<img>` tag from `<head>` and add it to body tag.

```
<body>
<img height="1" width="1" class="displaynone" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1007528252627508&ev=PageView&noscript=1">
</body>
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: i worked Pirate,i am confused about the tags can you post a good document about these tags

Answer (score 2):

You can't put `<img>` elements in the `<head>`, even if they are within a `<noscript>` element. They must go in the `<body>`.

Comment: What about Bing? ```<noscript><img></noscript>``` tag?

Comment: @Rastalamm — What does Bing have to do with it?

Comment: Bing uses that html structure in their tracking analytics... You can ignore the bing part